# Error en Lectura de Excel con DocumentFormat.OpenXml en VB.net

Tags: vb.net

Estoy leyendo un archivo .xlsx en VB.NET 2019 de la siguiente forma:

```
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet

Using spreadsheetDocument As SpreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stArchivo, False)
    Dim workbookPart As WorkbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart
    Dim worksheetPart As WorksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First()
    Dim sheetData As SheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements(Of SheetData)().First()

    For Each r As Row In sheetData.Elements(Of Row)()
        nCol = 0
        For Each c As Cell In r.Elements(Of Cell)()
            Debug.WriteLine(nCol.ToString & " - " & c.CellReference.ToString)
            nCol += 1
        Next
    Next
```

El problema que tengo es que, para algunas filas, se está saltando algunas columnas, como se muestra a continuación:

```
0 - A583
1 - B583
2 - C583
3 - D583
4 - E583
5 - F583
6 - G583
7 - I583 'Esto debería ser: 7 - H583
```

La Pregunta es Por qué pasa eso...???

Muchas Gracias
Atte.

Comment: Saludos. Se me ocurre lo siguiente; verifica que esa columna-fila tenga datos.

Comment: No tiene datos, de hecho al abrir el excel y hacer una inspección visual, esa celda se muestra vacia. Pero otras celdas vacias, si las reconoce.